# Perl only one option at a time

Tags: perl

There is a requirement where I can't put two options at the same time.

For instance with `-a` option:

```
file.pl -a file.text        # executes file
```

But if I write

```
file.pl -a -a file.text     # it is supposed to print a msg
```

or

```
file.pl -a -b file.text     # it is supposed to print a msg
```

Below is my script:

```
if ($ARGV[1] eq "-a" or "-b" or "-c" ) {

print "error \n"; }
```

The problem is even though I just write `file.pl -a file.text`, it still prints the msg.

Comment: Please stop posting Perl questions here; [programming questions are off-topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). If you're question-banned on SO, see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Answer (score 1):

That is not how logic operators work. You have to repeat the whole expression:

```
if ($ARGV[1] eq '-a' or $ARGV[1] eq '-b' or $ARGV[1] eq '-c') {
    print "Error\n";
}
```

If you do not want to repeat the ARGV part, you can use `grep`:

```
if (grep $_ eq $ARGV[1], qw(-a -b -c)) {
```

But, in fact, you are rather interested in the first character of the second argument, so this should work as well:

```
if (0 == index $ARGV[1], '-') {
```

What about `$ARGV[2]`?

Comment: if (0 == index $ARGV[1], '-') {      

how does this script exactly work?
and can you explain 0==index $ARGV[1] mean? thanks

Comment: @user2380840: [index](http://p3rl.org/index). It checks whether the 0th character in $ARGV[1] is '-'.

Comment: and if I have @data=<INFILE>

can it be:

if (grep @data eq  ??

Comment: @user2380840: What are you trying to achieve? Read [grep's documentation](http://p3rl.org/grep).

Comment: oh I was just wondering whether the syntax if(grep$_ is a reserved/given syntax?